# How to access directive's controller variables in directive's template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controlleras

Need to use variable (defined inside the **controller** element of directive) in the **template** element.

---

```js
angular.module('home').directive('mediaTile', function(){
 return {
  restrict: "AE",
  replace: 'true',
  scope: {
   media: '=',
   displayFilter: '='
  },
  controller: function($scope){
   var vm = this;
            vm.mediaImageActual = 'img/large-tiles.png';            }
  },
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  template:  '<div>' +
     '<img preload-image ng-src="{{vm.mediaImageActual}}">' +
     '</div>'
 };
});
```

```html
<div media-tile display-filter="view.displayFilter" media="dataList.lists[0]"></div>
```

ng-src is not getting the proper value i.e vm.mediaImageActual.

I have tried online solutions like [this](http://juristr.com/blog/2015/01/learning-ng-directives-access-scope-controller/) but unable to resolve the issue.
Whats wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

script.js

```
var app = angualr.module('app', []);
app.directive('mediaTile', function(){
return {
    restrict: "AE",
    replace: 'true',
    scope: {
        media: '=',
        displayFilter: '='
    },
    controller: function($scope){
        var vm = this;
        vm.mediaImageActual = 'img/large-tiles.png';
    },
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    template: '<div>{{vm.mediaImageActual}}"' +
                '</div>'
};
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div media-tile displayFilter="view.displayFilter" media="dataList.lists[0]"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Charan, yes you are right there was an extra '}'. This might have been added while editing the question in stack overflow tool.
The actual issue is I am unable to access the variables defined in directive's controller in directive's template.

Comment: Try without controllerAs syntax

Comment: There is no problem with your code. its just working fine, but the path of the image may be not correct. But I am able to access variables. https://plnkr.co/edit/Y2cJrUGYcygvM9i6wKx5?p=preview just find the variable of your directive in `script.js`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `bindToController: true` in the directive.

You can find more details [here](https://toddmotto.com/no-scope-soup-bind-to-controller-angularjs/)

> Use bindToController alongside controllerAs syntax, which treats Controllers as Class-like Objects, instantiating them as constructors and allowing us to namespace them once instantiated

If your are using angularJs1.6 or above, you can use `component` instead of directive which has all these properties set by default

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: @Developer: Thanks :) but unfortunately, I am using angularjs 1.3.

Comment: @shahidbits - in that case you can set `bindToController` to true in the directive